# Looking for a User Agent String to detect the kind of cell phone?

Tags: mobile, user-agent

Does anyone know a good user agent string that will tell me if the cell phone is an iPhone, Blackberry, Android, DumbPhone??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [WURFL](http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/). It has a device capability database, and an associated API for PHP and Java that matches user agents to devices in the database. And it's free.

A commercial alternative is [DeviceAtlas](http://deviceatlas.com/), but API is a good deal more primitive than WURFL's.